# Unequal sample sizes in generalized linear modeling

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sample-size, predictor

I would appreciate your advice.

I have a number of outcome variables that follow Normal, Gamma or Poisson distribution. The predictor is categorical with two levels, as follows: 
Category 1: N=321, 9.3% of the sample
Category 2: N=3145, 90.7% of the sample

I understand that unequal cell size is a problem in ANOVA/regression/GLM.  How can I run GLM analyses with above-mentioned distributions and unbalanced predictor?

Comment: @Naatalie: I understand your question to pertain to generalized linear models only.  If I misunderstood you, please feel free to change my edit.

Comment: Michael, most of the time I use generalized LM since the data is not normally distributed. So the question pertains to the GLM with a variety of distribution, depending on the outcome variable.

Comment: That is exactly how I interpreted it.  My changes were very minor and in the title I changed "generalized general modeling" to "generalized linear modeling" because the term "general" seems redundant  and the restriction to linear models was missing.